# Windows Universal UserControl Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, win-universal-app

I have created a UserControl for a Windows Universal app.

I have a property in my code behind file called HourList defined thus...

```
internal ObservableCollection<int> HourList = 
     new ObservableCollection<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                           12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 };
```

I want to use the HourList to bind controls to within my UserControl's xaml, for example...

```
<ListView Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding HourList, ElementName=timePicker}"
</ListView>
```

This assumes that I have named my UserControl like this...

```
<UserControl x:Name="timePicker"
```

When I place the control on a page however, my listview doesn't contain a list of hours as I expect.

What have I missed?

Comment: you need to set the datacontext, the `ElementName` binding doesn't make any sense IMO, but without more code it's hard to tell

Comment: Like @thumbmunkeys has mentioned, need some more information here on your UserControl. Due to the way you're doing your binding, the HourList would need to a property or dependencyproperty on your UserControl. If you're intending to bind to the HourList on the datacontext of your UserControl, use DataContext.HourList for your binding. Also, make your collection public so it can be seen by the control.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a property in the code-behind of your user control:

```
public ObservableCollection<int> HourList
{
    get;
    set;
}
public UserControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    HourList = new ObservableCollection<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 };                
}
```

However at some point if you need to bind to it or do animations, then you will need it to be a dependency property like below:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HourListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HourList",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(MyUserControl1), 
    new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<int> 
    { 
      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
      14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23 
    }));

public ObservableCollection<int> HourList
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<int>)this.GetValue(HourListProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetValue(HourListProperty, value); 
    }
}
```

Either way the XAML is the same:

```
<StackPanel>
    <UserControl x:Name="timePicker" />
        <ListView         
        Height="100"
        Foreground="Black"            
        Width="100" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=timePicker, Path=HourList}">
        </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```